# Spring Batch Job takes very long to read from db and write to csv file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have written this configuration file to read from the db and write to a CSV file.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Start imports -->
<import resource="launch-context.xml"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<!-- End imports -->

<job id="DLM" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <step id="siebelToStaging" next="generateControlReport">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="DbReader" writer="outputFileWriter" commit-interval="10"> </chunk>
            <!--
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="dbReaderStepExecutionListener"/>
            </listeners>
            -->
        </tasklet>
    </step>

    <!-- Step 2 -->
    <step id="generateControlReport">
        <tasklet ref="generateControlReportTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="jobListener"/>
    </listeners>
</job>
<!-- End job -->    

<bean id="jobListener" class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.listener.GenericJobExecutionListener">
    <property name="eaiJobExecution" ref="eaiJobExecution"/>
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"/>
</bean> 

<!--
<bean id="dbReaderStepExecutionListener" class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.listener.DbStepExecutionListenerImpl">
    <property name="eaiJobExecution" ref="eaiJobExecution"/>
    <property name="updLastWritableStepCtxId" value="true"/>
    <property name="updLastReadableStepCtxId" value="true"/>
</bean>
-->

<!-- Assigning values to parameter variable -->
<bean id="eaiJobExecution" class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.job.EaiJobExecution">
    <property name="parameter">
        <bean class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.job.Parameter">
            <property name="fileDateFmt" value="yyyyMMDDhhmmss"/>
            <property name="fileHeaderDateFmt" value="yyyyMMDDhhmmss"/>
            <property name="totalRecordsFmt" value="10N"/>
            <property name="sequenceFmt" value="4N"/>
            <property name="sequenceName" value="003_SEQ"/>
            <property name="outputDir" value="/outbox/new"/>
            <property name="reportDir" value="/ctlrpt"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.dao.BatchJobDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="generateControlReportTasklet" class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.tasklet.GenerateControlReportTasklet">
    <property name="ctrlReportDir" ref="reportDirResource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="controlReport" class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.dataobject.ControlReport"/>

<bean id="reportDirResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg value="../ctlrpt"/>
</bean>

<!-- ItemReader which reads from Siebel database and returns the row mapped by rowMapper - START-->

<bean id="DbReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />

    <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[SELECT STX.serial_num     
                        FROM   cityDB
                    WHERE  MODEM.prod_id = (SELECT row_id 
                                FROM   s_prod_int 
                                WHERE  name = 'Modem' 
                                       AND ROWNUM < 2) 
               AND status_cd <> 'Inactive' 
               AND par_asset_id = row_id]]>
            </value>
    </property>

    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="my.com.tm.hsbb.eai.batch.transform.DynamicLineManagementRowMapper" />
    </property>

</bean>
<!-- ItemReader which reads from  database and returns the row mapped by rowMapper - END-->

<!-- SBL DB Connectivity configuration -->
<bean id="DataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">

    <property name="driverType" value="${db_driver}"/>
    <property name="URL" value="${db_url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${db_user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db_password}"/>

</bean>

<!-- Writing the file - START -->
<bean id = "outputFileWriter" class = "org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
  <property name = "resource" value = "file:/new/LINE_ICP_#{jobParameters[dateCreated]}#{jobParameters[timeCreated]}.txt"/>
  <property name = "lineAggregator">
     <bean class = " org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator"/>
  </property>
</bean>
<!-- Writing the file - END -->
```

This is the simplest spring-batch configuration file I have ever written, yet this is the batch job that took 9 hours to write a file that is 10MB in size and has 69507 lines. I have done away with most of the lines that may refer to classes and interfaces that might have caused the bottlenecks yet it still takes a long time.

Could some one please advise me on what else I can do reduce the processing time? If the information that I have provided is insufficient, you can let me know. (p.s some of the namespaces in  had to be removed as the system recognizes them as hyperlinks, also the sql query has been shortened)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the performance of the query itself?

Comment: I have run the query on a TOAD, and it takes a few minutes.

Comment: So the query is (relatively slow). What does your `DynamicLineManagementRowMapper` do? Also 10 as the commit interval is a bit low try something like 100. Also what takes a long time, the reading or the writing?

Comment: I think it is the reading that is taking the longest. I thought the RowMapper was compulsory.

Comment: I second M. Deinum. Try with a bigger chunk size like 100 or 1000 and see what happens. Moreover, make sure columns in the select statements are indexed (this may improve your query's execution time). Also, it could be that `step2` or your `jobListener` (which is referring to a dao) are taking time too. Have you measured the the duration of each step?

Comment: Hi  Mahmoud, may I know how to measure the duration of each step?

Comment: You can use a `StepExecutionListener` and record the startTime and endTime in the `beforeStep` and `afterStep` methods.